# Joomla overwrite media css

Tags: joomla

I am trying to create an overwrite for a css located at:

```
/media/com_acymailing/css/module_default.css
```

I created a path and file at:

```
/templates/{mytemplate}/css/com_acymailing/css/module_default.css
```

This does not seem to work. Do I have the overwrite path wrong?

Comment: See the answers to http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/3877/120 for the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct path should be `/templates/{mytemplate}/css/com_acymailing/module_default.css`